# Storing Strings and Integers from .txt file to a Dictionary in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, dictionary

I want my program to take the subspecies title (ex. 'Ablepharus bivittatus') and store that as a string key. Then I want the program to take the following lines of sequence IDs (integers) up *until* the next subspecies title. The integers will be stored as the values to the subspecies key that was originally grabbed above.

I want the program to be able to prompt the user for a string input, then the input would be searched through all the dictionary keys to find an exact match (case sensitive, and spelling matters here) and then return the sequences IDs.

What would be the most efficient way to do this? Right now I can separate the two entities (IDs and Subspecies names) but I have no idea how to create a dictionary to store these values while iterating over the text file.

Some of the lines contain the same name, but is repeated multiple times, how would I be able to tell the program to detect that and only match the first of the multiple identical subspecies names as one string key?

The text file has this format below

Thanks for your time

```
Ablepharus bivittatus   
36630
31764
31212
01996
09953
03744
14036
16094
01875
19076
09496
20583
24160
23142
26892
06533
05488
Ablepharus chernovi Ablepharus chernovi chernovi DAREVSKY 1953
Ablepharus chernovi eiselti SCHMIDTLER 1997
Ablepharus chernovi isauriensis SCHMIDTLER 1997
Ablepharus chernovi ressli SCHMIDTLER 1997
31212
01996
09637
14036
20583
23142
21989
26892
28697
09207
09206
Ablepharus darvazi  
06245
26892
```

Here's some code I've been messing with so far on this.

```
dictionary = {}

with open("repCleanSubs2.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        dictionary[val(key)] = val
print key(1)







'''import re
file = open('repCleanSubs2.txt')
subspecies = []
dnaIDs = []
for line in file:
    match = re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', line)
        if match:
            subspecies.append(line)
            #Grab sequence IDs under this line ^ 
            #
            #Until you reach next string match





print dnaIDs
#userInput = raw_input("Which subspecies would you like to view?: ")
#if userInput == re.match(subspecies(line)):
#   print subspecies(line)'''
# print sequences IDs from the line grabbed here ^`
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to use `file.read().splitlines()` to get a list of the lines.
2. Iterating through the lines and checking whether they are a new subspecies or an ID seems to be the most appropriate.
3. You can then use the "current" name during iteration as the dictionary key, and add the new ID to that list.

This seems to do what you're asking:

```
import re


data = {}
lines = []

with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
name = ""
for l in lines:
    if re.match("\d{5}", l):
        data[name].append(l)
    else:
        name = l.strip()
        data[name] = []

print data
```

It results in the following output:

```
{
    "Ablepharus chernovi isauriensis SCHMIDTLER 1997": [], 
    "Ablepharus bivittatus": [
        "36630", 
        "31764", 
        "31212", 
        "01996", 
        "09953", 
        "03744", 
        "14036", 
        "16094", 
        "01875", 
        "19076", 
        "09496", 
        "20583", 
        "24160", 
        "23142", 
        "26892", 
        "06533", 
        "05488"
    ], 
    "Ablepharus chernovi ressli SCHMIDTLER 1997": [
        "31212", 
        "01996", 
        "09637", 
        "14036", 
        "20583", 
        "23142", 
        "21989", 
        "26892", 
        "28697", 
        "09207", 
        "09206"
    ], 
    "Ablepharus darvazi": [
        "06245", 
        "26892"
    ], 
    "Ablepharus chernovi eiselti SCHMIDTLER 1997": [], 
    "Ablepharus chernovi Ablepharus chernovi chernovi DAREVSKY 1953": []
}
```

I'm uncertain as to what you mean by some lines contain the same name repeated, if you could elaborate on that point and indicate your expected output then that could be incorporated.

Lastly, returning the sequence ID's for a given key provided by the user would look like this:

```
print(data[raw_input()])
```

Comment: `Ablepharus chernovi Ablepharus chernovi chernovi DAREVSKY 1953
Ablepharus chernovi eiselti SCHMIDTLER 1997
Ablepharus chernovi isauriensis SCHMIDTLER 1997
Ablepharus chernovi ressli SCHMIDTLER 1997
 31212
01996
09637
14036
20583
23142
21989
26892
28697
09207`

So for example these four names should only be counted as one key, how would I be able to tell the program to detect multiple names for a set of 1 sequence IDs.?

Comment: When the user looks up that key, do they need to type any one of the 4 names or the entire string together? i.e. one like `Ablepharus chernovi Ablepharus chernovi chernovi DAREVSKY 1953` or the entire thing `Ablepharus chernovi Ablepharus chernovi chernovi DAREVSKY 1953 Ablepharus chernovi eiselti SCHMIDTLER 1997 Ablepharus chernovi isauriensis SCHMIDTLER 1997 Ablepharus chernovi ressli SCHMIDTLER 1997`?